# Integrating MySQL connection into a Java program

Tags: java, mysql

I am creating a project for my computing class. I have created a program for my project that stores all of the passwords for the user at 1 location(the program I am creating) so that the user doesn't have to remember all of their different passwords.

I have currently used a MySQL database to hold all of the usernames and passwords for the existing users.So the login procedure goes something like this:

1.Connection is established to MySQL connection
2. users enters name and password into Java form
3. SQL query checks if name and passwords matched that in database.
4. if it does then the user gets in else they are told to re-enter the name and password.

I would like to export my program as 1 program, but i am not sure if i would need to export the MySQL connection too. is there any way that i would be able to export this program and the SQL database as 1 large program or will the end user have to be told to install MySQL and also the program that i have created to use my program?

Is it possible to integrate  a MySQL connection into a Java program?

Comment: of course you can, you need to use a Java mySql Connector library to mount the connection to it and then do the relevant operations that you will need

Comment: You basically have two options. You can host php scripts on some server that communicate with MySQL, and your Java program communicates with those through POST requests. The other option is to use [Connector/J](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/) to connect to MySQL directly from Java.

Comment: i think that i may have said the question a bit wrong. to rephrase it, when i export the whole program as a fully complete package that can be sent to the end user, is there a way in which i can add the MySQL connection into the fully done program or will i always have to tell the end user to download MySQL to make the program work? I have already connected up my program to the MySQL database using the connector.